# Can I create a child class out of a parent class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, clone

Lets say I have a class that is responsible for composing another class:

```
class ClassBuilder
{
    protected $baseClass;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->baseClass = new BaseClass();
    }

    public function set()
    {
        $this->baseClass->foo = 'bar';
    }

    // other methods to further modify BaseClass
}

class BaseClass
{
    public $foo;
}
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {}
```

I want to create a method in the `ClassBuilder` that would allow me to update its `baseClass` property to an instance of `ChildClass` with the same property values as the current BaseClass object. How can I do that?

```
public function update()
{
    // $this->baseClass = new ChildClass() with the current property values in BaseClass
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're after the [factory pattern](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-the-factory-method-design-pattern), though I don't believe your implementation is entirely correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that your overall approach is correct, but about the only way is to loop and set:

```
public function update()
{
    $new = new ChildClass();

    foreach($this->baseClass as $name => $value) {
        $new->$name = $value;
    }   
    $this->baseClass =  $new;
    //or
    $this->baseClass = clone $new;
}
```

Comment: I suppose if the properties were in fact `protected` instead of public, that I'd have to use reflection, right?

Comment: Yes I was going by `public $foo;`.  You then have an issue of setting them.  You may look into implementing the `__get()` in `BaseClass` and `__set()` in `ChildClass`, and/or method(s) in them to return or set an array of properties.